# Is there a faster way to create a Point from a text offset with AvalonEdit?

Tags: c#, wpf, avalonedit

I am currently drawing in a BackgroundRenderer based on the text, so I need to convert from an offset to a Point, but I have found that this process is slowing down my application (and it's not the actual drawing part but rather getting the Point from the offset).

This is what I am doing currently:

```
var textLocation = textView.Document.GetLocation(offset);
var textViewPos = new TextViewPosition(textLocation);
var point = textView.GetVisualPosition(textViewPos, VisualYPosition.LineBottom);
point -= textView.ScrollOffset;
```

How can I make this more efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid calling your code with offsets outside the visible region.
`GetVisualPosition` is slow if the line is not visible, because in that case there won't be any cached layout for the line; so AvalonEdit has to perform text layout in order to return the correct X coordinate.

You can use `GetVisualTopByDocumentLine` and `GetDocumentLineByVisualTop` to efficiently convert between Y coordinates and line numbers without triggering text layout.